# Does G-d's closeness necessitate anthropomorphism?

Tags: theology

A big part of our Jewish theology and philosophy is based on our desire to be closer to G-d (hope it's accepted unanimously). All of our analogies are built around the personification of G-d, whether we refer to Him as the Master/the King, the Father or the Spouse.

But let's try to visualize a greater view of G-d, like Rambam's. Let's imagine that we relate to G-d as amebas or ants relate to us. In this view, all the aforementioned analogies are invalid and irrelevant as our scopes of intelligence are incompatible. And, therefore, no communication or interaction is possible on any level of sophistication higher than ours.

So everything G-d does for us, in our imagination, has to be in human terms - speed, volume, value, etc. For example, if G-d wants to pass some information He needs to SPEAK/write, word by word, in an acceptable voice and comprehensible language (imagery), at the speed and volume of our understanding (He can't give us Torah 15Gb in size - that's incomprehensible). In other words, manifest human qualities. If He FEELS, the range of His emotions perfectly mimics ours.

Therefore it appears that the Jewish theology necessitates G-d's anthropomorphism in order to maintain its beliefs (see Raavad's comment to [Rambam Hilchot Teshuva 3,7](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Repentance.3.7?lang=he&p2=Hasagot_HaRaavad_on_Mishneh_Torah%2C_Repentance.3.7.1&lang2=he)):

> (וְהָאוֹמֵר שֶׁיֵּשׁ שָׁם רִבּוֹן אֶחָד אֲבָל שֶׁהוּא גּוּף וּבַעַל תְּמוּנָה (נקרא מין.
>   ראב"ד: ולמה קרא לזה מין **וכמה גדולים וטובים ממנו
>
>   הלכו בזו המחשבה לפי מה שראו במקראות
>
>   ויותר ממה שראו בדברי האגדות המשבשות את הדעות**:

So do our basic concepts *necessitate* viewing G-d as anthropomorphic?

Comment: I think the Rambam would agree about "our scopes of intelligence are incompatible." And I think he would disagree about "therefore, no communication or interaction is possible." How do you reach that conclusion?

Comment: @ba Accepted, my bad. I edited the sentence.

Comment: @ba, Al Berko is right. The correct view of the Rambam is that we cannot know anything abut G-d except for what G-d is not. Therefore, there is no way to communicate or interact with G-d. The best we can do is to study G-d. That is, 1) study Torah, 2) show love of G-d, and 3) study G-d's creation (the earth and natural law).

Comment: This simple answer is: We should not view G-d as being anthropomorphic (G-d has no body).

Comment: @TurkHill And what about prayer?

Comment: @AlBerko It is the opinion of some commentators that G-d does not listen to prayer. The Rambam, although engaged in the topic of prayer many times might have felt this way. He might have seen prayer as a way of reflecting oneself. In any event, people should fend for themselves and not rely on G-d to perform miracles.

Comment: @TurkHill I think I was greatly misunderstood. I stated that 1. we have no way of imaging G-d but as a man (because of limitations on our side) 2. This perception is crucial in Judaism because all of our interactions with Him are "allegorically" human - He's our Master, king, father, spouse etc. If we remove this anthropomorphism, so who do we pray to? Who's gonna judge us? Who's pleased with our Mitzvos? Therefore I conclude that anthropomorphism is innate and necessary to Judaism. Hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Why would something potentially misleading like "charon Apo" be in the Torah if it weren't necessary?

Comment: @MichaBerger Exactly, You support my point. I claim such human presentations ARE absolutely crucial to our understanding of the G-dly reality. And if we transcend to a higher level of G-d that does not get angry we can't parse the Torah at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96437/discussion-between-al-berko-and-turk-hill).

Comment: @Al Berko אתה חייב ללמוד דעת תבונות להרמח"ל, הרבה מהשאלות שלך מתורצים בו. בענין זה הוא כותב, אם הבנתי נכון, שמערכת היסודי של העולם, הספירות, נבראו כדי שבני אדם יהיו יכולים להבין אותם.ב

Comment: @Mordechai What does it have to do with anthropomorphism?

Comment: @AlBerko have you ever learned the whole of Moreh Nevuchim? It lays out a whole approach to closeness to Hashem without leaning on any form of anthropomorphism.

Comment: @RabbiKaii Yes, in fact, I did, not the whole, though I admit I don't agree with him. As a true Aristotelian, Rambam denies anthropomorphism axiomatically. For him, it is not a conclusion for him, it is a starting point. He only spoke of intellectual closeness, which is far from most mainstream Hassidic and orthodox approaches. It was only adopted later by the Litvakes.

Comment: @AlBerko possibly an answer to your question then? As you say, anthropomorphism is a useful, in fact important starting point, but, from Rambam's point of view, not necessary, and in fact something to move beyond as an ideal. It may not be considered mainstream, but it seems to be a legitimate point of view nonetheless (I'm also not a huge fan of it, but I see the truth in it).

Comment: @RabbiKaii My point is that the two approaches are incompatible: you either see God as a transcendent entity or as a father/king/spouse, etc. None of our liturgies applies to the former.

Comment: @AlBerko Interestingly, I am currently on a long term project to get to the bottom of exactly this point. If I ever publish, I'll let you know! What do you think of the "deopomorphic" solution? I.e. marriage, having children, these are Godly concepts, our version is a finite mashal of something transcendent

Comment: @RabbiKaii I couldn't Google "deopomorphic", what is that? What you say is classical Platonism - objects in our world are the realization of abstract/heavenly ideas/forms. A horse is a materialization of heavenly horsesness, a chair is an example of divine chairness, etc. He is thus the spiritual father of Pharisee/Rabbinic Judaism.

Comment: Oh @AlBerko, it would be so great to discuss this at length with you. Either way, I think we've pushed the length of this comments section far enough without getting moderated, it's hard to describe the similarities and differences between the platonic world and what we mean by "Divine" in Torah in under 500 characters (which generally forces us to compactify anyway, which is why I made up the word "deopomorphic")

Answer (score -3):

The correct view of the Rambam is that we cannot know anything abut G-d except for what G-d is not. G-d does not listen to prayers because He already knows them in advance (Gd knows everything).

The characteristics such as wisdom are like the ones found in the Bible. Because the Torah (as Rabbi Ishmael says, it [Torah] “speaks in the language people use,”). It follows that he Torah was written for (in) human language (understanding,) thus we should not take G-d’s emotions literally (G-d has no emotions). It follows that G-d does not really becomes angry when you miss the mark and make a sin. Yet G-d’s wisdom (or chachmah) cannot be compared. Think of our DNA. Someone had to be very intelligent to create that. “For your ways are not My ways,” says Hashem.

Rather than put G-d to an image (humanly) we should try and imitate Hashem. G-d gave us the mitzvahs for this very purpose. When one studies Torah, they experience perfection. You could boil it down some more. Man has a purpose. This is what is meant when we say the Will of G-d. King David primary insisted that the world gives praise anthropomorphically to G-d. That is, that our praise should reflect the impressive brilliance of the design and magnificence of the world. That is to our understanding of Him. Maimonides says, “In accordance with one’s knowledge [of G-d] is one’s love of G-d.” Thus, we should center our praise to the Name of Hashem because we cannot know anything about G-d except for what G-d is not (G-d has no body and is one). All we can know is G-d's creations, natural law. Therefore, people should develop their intellect and learn from the laws of nature (science). For example, when the Bible speaks about the parable of G-d talking to Moshe, it is to be understood that people cannot fathom the divine, but see His back after He passes. It is referring to the impact of natural law that G-d created.

For “Man cannot know Me while alive.” Thus, we can only praise G-d through His name, acts, and fame. Though we cannot picture an image of letters while praising. We should not draw an image of G-d in our head. G-d should not be a person, a character, or an angel when we pray rather, G-d should be viewed as nothing because G-d does not exist. In other words, G-d is beyond the domain of existence. In order for G-d to exist, He would have to be made of some kind of material or substance, and hence a form that can be discovered. (Abraham discovered G-d by studying the heaven but this is metaphorical). G-d's essence is nothing, so you can and should picture nothing when you pray.